# How do I copy a folder into the temp directory?

Tags: java

I would like to copy a folder

c:\data

into C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Temp as is.

So then the path would be

C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Temp\data

Here is what I have so far

```
public void copyToTemp(File source){
    try {
        File dest = File.createTempFile(source.getName(), null);
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest);

        //change the source folder to the temp folder
        SOURCE_FOLDER = dest.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard `java.nio.file.Files.copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)`.
See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.nio.file/Files/Java_Files_copy_Path_source_Path_target_CopyOption_options_.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
String tempPath = System.getenv("TEMP");
```

This reads the windows environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void copyToTemp(String source){
        File sourceFolder = new File(source);
        final String tempLocation = "C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\";
        File tempFolder = new File(tempLocation + sourceFolder.getName());

        tempFolder.mkdir();

        try{
            copy(sourceFolder, tempFolder);
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Failed to copy file/folder to temp location.");
        }

    }

    private void copy(File sourceLocation, File targetLocation) throws IOException{
        if(sourceLocation.isDirectory()){
            copyDirectory(sourceLocation, targetLocation);
        } else{
            copyFile(sourceLocation, targetLocation);
        }
    }

    private void copyDirectory(File source, File target) throws IOException{
        if(!target.exists()){
            target.mkdir();
        }

        for(String f : source.list()){
            copy(new File(source, f), new File(target, f));
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(File source, File target) throws IOException{
        try(
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target)){
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while((length = in.read(buf)) > 0){
                out.write(buf, 0, length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps, Luke.